# How can i make multidimensional array in nodejs loop?

Tags: node.js

I want like this:-

```
Array
    (
        [sys_dropdowns] => Array
            (
                [branchs] => Array
                    (
                        [branchs.branchs_id] => Array
                            (
                                [permission] => %BRANCHS_PRIVILEGE
                                [no_permission] => 
                                [sql_where_clause] => 
                            )
    
                    )
            )
    
        [sys_master_grid] => Array
            (
                [draft_voucher_list] => Array
                    (
                        [acc_voucher_main.branchs_id] => Array
                            (
                                [permission] => %BRANCHS_PRIVILEGE
                                [no_permission] => 
                                [sql_where_clause] => 
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
        )
    
    )
```

I am trying this :-

```
var all_permission = []; 
    sql_data.forEach(function(val) {
        if (all_permission[val.event_ref] === undefined) all_permission[val.event_ref] = [];
        if (all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] === undefined) all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] = [];
        all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug][val.event_slug_key] = {
            permission:val.permission,
            no_permission:val.no_permission,
            sql_where_clause:val.sql_where_clause
        }
    });
```

But when i return all_permission variable its send blank array but when i console all_permission its shows exactly what i want. if i push single value then also send perfect result but when i try to create multi then arise this issue.
Please help how can i return multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing between `array` and `object`. Try something like this

```
var all_permission = {}; 
sql_data.forEach(function(val) {
    if (type of all_permission[val.event_ref] === 'undefined') all_permission[val.event_ref] = {};
    if (typeof all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] === 'undefined') all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] = {};
    all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug][val.event_slug_key] = {
        permission:val.permission,
        no_permission:val.no_permission,
        sql_where_clause:val.sql_where_clause
    }
});
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks bro @Foysal Nibir.